# Android -have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to read some data from an online server and add them dynamically in a ListView. Unfortunately it crashes with an `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException`but my activity is declared in the manifest so I don't understand what the problem is.

This is my java file:

```
public class Marker extends Activity {


    // Retrieve COMMENTS from database
    String myJSON;

    private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_POI = "poi";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME ="username";
    private static final String TAG_COMMENT = "comment";

    JSONArray comments = null;


    // ListView
    private ListView lv;
    private ArrayList<String> strArr;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_marker);


        // Retrieve COMMENTS from database
        getData();
    }

    // Retrieve COMMENTS from database
    protected void showList(){
        try {

            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            strArr = new ArrayList<String>();


            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            comments = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

            for(int i=0;i<comments.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = comments.getJSONObject(i);
                Integer id = c.getInt(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_POI);
                String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                String comment = c.getString(TAG_COMMENT);

                strArr.add("Row:" + comment);
            }

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strArr);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void getData(){
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxx/comments_out.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;
                showList();
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_marker_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.diana.track.MarkerPage">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.diana.track" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".myprofile"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_myprofile" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Track"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_track" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".map"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notification_view" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProximityActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_proximity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddPoi"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_poi" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShortPath"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_short_path" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".profile"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Marker"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_marker" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my logcat

```
07-16 18:34:27.659    8628-9083/com.example.diana.track D/-heap﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3574K, 38% free 7122K/11376K, paused 57ms, total 65ms
07-16 18:34:28.059    8628-8628/com.example.diana.track I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-16 18:34:28.440    8628-9075/com.example.diana.track D/-heap﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1605K, 35% free 7482K/11376K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
07-16 18:34:29.050    8628-9083/com.example.diana.track D/-heap﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 501K, 33% free 7648K/11376K, paused 33ms, total 35ms
07-16 18:34:29.050    8628-9083/com.example.diana.track I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 11.080MB for 1048592-byte allocation
07-16 18:34:30.041    8628-8628/com.example.diana.track D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-16 18:34:30.041    8628-8628/com.example.diana.track W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415478b0)
07-16 18:34:30.061    8628-8628/com.example.diana.track E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.diana.track/com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
            at com.example.diana.track.map.onMarkerClick(map.java:765)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$10.zza(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzn$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:347)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bd.a(SourceFile:84)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.as.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.e.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.av.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.be.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.bd.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.bt.d(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.ak.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.h.g.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.h.i.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Try renaming it to `MarkerActivity`, it looks like it's a conflict with the `com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker` class.

Comment: Check your activity is in the correct package. ie, com.example.diana.track. Marker

Comment: @DanielNugent thank you! That was the problem! Now it works perfectly!! Thank you very much!